# How to make a private edit on a shared Google Spreadsheet

Tags: google-sheets

I'd like to make some notes/mark some cells privately on a shared Google Spreadsheet in Google Drive. Is this possible?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured out a work-a-round and this is how to do it:

**Shared file with edit rights**

1. Create a new sheet
2. Protect sheet (*Tools, Protect sheet*) and set to **me only**
3. Set the color of the font to white

Now you're able to make notes without anybody seeing them. If you want to see them, select the cell to see the content of that cell. It won't appear in the cell itself, but to the right of the *Fx* symbol at the top of your screen:
[image]

Other users can't edit the sheet, thus can't control the font color.
This solution only works, if you set the sheet color to be white !!

Comment: Good idea on first glance, but definitely some privacy issues! The document with all it's (white) text is still downloaded by other clients and the text can easily be read in the browsers developer console.